# Is Ice Age series fit for this site?

Tags: discussion

Ice Age shows Mammoths, Dinosaurs, the ice age, continental drift. But, at the same time, nothing's really serious. A guy run on the core of the Earth to change environment.

Can Ice Age questions be asked on this site?

Answer (score 10):

It's a tricky one. The main film series is best described as a "[**computer-animated comedy-drama adventure** film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Age_(2002_film))".

In and of itself, the films are neither science fictional, nor especially fantastical (talking animals don't make a film a fantasy) and the main topic  of the first two film (the ice age) is an historical event. The third film obviously has a more fantastical aspect (dinosaurs vs mammoths)

On the other hand, some *elements* of the film series do contain strong sci-fi. It would definitely be on-topic to ask about those.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I consider this type of movie as a historical movie with sci-fi and some fantasy stuff put in. So even though it revolves around historical events it does include some sci-fi and fantasy elements in it. So in theory it's both suitable and unsuitable.
In my opinion I would not downvote any question based on the Ice age series unless the question is "When did the Ice Age happen?"